# create relative url for category and subcategory in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

There is problem in wordpress url. I have created custom post-type and custom-taxonomy. When i click on category then following url is appear in url bar.

```
root/product-category/category
```

When in click on subcategory then it shows tha following url.

```
root/product-category/subcategory
```

But i want to show following url,

```
root/product-category/category/subcategory
```

Here is code for custom post type,

```
    add_action('init','rf_main_products');
function rf_main_products(){
    $args=array
        (
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Products'),
                'singular_name' => __('Product'),
                'add_new' => __('Add New Product'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Product'),
                'new_item' => __('New Product'),
                'view_item' => __('View Product'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Product'),
                'not_found' =>  __('No Product found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Product found in Trash'),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mainproducts'),
            'supports'=>array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
            'hierarchical'=>true,
            'taxonomies'=>array('main_product_category','tags')
        );
    register_post_type('rf_main_products',$args);
}
```

Comment: Try changing woocommerce permalink settings

Comment: But i am not using woocommerce.

Comment: Should have appeared in root/prod-cat/cat/sub format... Maybe your parent category is not assigned to your sub category ??

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-categories-and-subcategories-to-wordpress/

Comment: I know how to add category and subcategory in wordpress. Please :)

Comment: Then show me your custom post type register code

Comment: Please check custom post type code.